# CKAN - use API with curl and Apache basic authentication

Tags: apache, ckan

I create resources in Ckan using curl and everything works:

`curl -H'Authorization: zzzzzz-zzzzz-zzzzz-zzzzz-zzzzzz' 'https://ckan.site.com/api/action/resource_create' --form upload=@/home/file.csv --form package_id=test-upload-file --form url='' --form name='test 12' --form format='csv'`

But if Ckan is on an Apache web server with basic-auth (so when I try to log into the web interface a popup asking for username and password appears) curl stops working. I add -u option to curl command to pass username and password to the web server, but I always receive an "Unauthorized" answer from Apache; I also tried passing username and password with http://username:password@ckan.site.com or with -n and .netrc file, but I had no luck.

I am suspecting that Apache is messing with "Authorization" header: one is passed with curl and -H option, and another because there is basic authentication configured in Apache  ([documentation here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization)) ... maybe they mix up?
If I try to simply `curl -n https://ckan.site.com/` I can download Ckan homepage.

Here is Apache basic auth configuration:

```
<Location />
AuthType Basic
AuthName "ckan login"
AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
</Location>
```

And here is the auth_basic error that I see in Apache logs:

`client used wrong authentication scheme: /api/action/resource_create`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTTP Basic Auth, like many other HTTP authentication schemes, uses the [`Authorization`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization) header to pass credentials from the client to the server. This clashes with CKAN's requirement of using the `Authorization` header for passing the API key.

When you manually set the `Authorization` header in curl you override the value that would be set for Basic Auth. You can test that yourself using, for example, `netcat`. Here's the `GET` request curl produces for Basic Auth:

```
curl 'http://user:pass@localhost:8080'
```

Output from `netcat -l 8080`:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Authorization: Basic dXNlcjpwYXNz
User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
Accept: */*
```

As you can see, curl has filled the `Authorization` header with the encoded credentials for user `user` and password `pass`.

Now let's try the same and also specify a value for `Authorization` manually:

```
curl -H'Authorization: Foo' 'http://user:pass@localhost:8080'
```

Output from `netcat`:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
Accept: */*
Authorization: Foo
```

Our custom value has overridden the one for Basic Auth. Apache would now interpret `Foo` (or, in your case, your API key) as the name of an HTTP authentication scheme (like `Basic` before) -- and since it doesn't fit the scheme that you're using to protect the URL Apache raises the error you've seen (`client used wrong authentication scheme`).

To avoid this problem, CKAN also accepts API keys in the `X-CKAN-API-Key` header. You can even set your own name for the header using CKAN's [`api_key_header_name`](https://docs.ckan.org/en/2.8/maintaining/configuration.html#apikey-header-name) config option.